# Assigning 'selected' to options of multiple select element

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a comma separated list stored in mysql(I used implode after selections were made and stored this comma separated list).  My problem is now applying 'selected="selected"' to each option that represents a previous choice when my page is refreshed.  I have used a while loop to create the select box.  I tried using a foreach loop inside of my while loop to check whether or not the 'while' value was in the 'exploded' previous selections. It only gave the value of 'selected' to the last item in my exploded list. Can anyone shed light on how to solve this problem?  I think I am misunderstanding foreach and possibly the explode function.

Comment: Can you post some code samples?

Comment: As you see now storing multiple values in a single column only gives you headaches. Can you change your DB design?

Comment: Do you mean before a form is submitted? However, why do you have a comma separated list in a single MySQL column?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your previous selected items are in a variable $selected, and your while looks as follows:

```
$selected = array('one', 'two');
while(//your fech or something i presume storing it in $row) {
    $isSelected = in_array($row['value'],$selected) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    echo "<option {$isSelected} value='{$row['value']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you all.  Yes Liam and Juergen I should not store comma separated values in a field but I couldn't figure out how to deal with the additional table. @ taxicala, your solution worked once I added your array variable $selected to the in_array function.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my code, it´s not perfect but works!:

```
$var_options = array ( 1 => 
array ('name' => "None", 'varid' => "0"),
array ('name' => "Cars", 'varid' => "1"),
array ('name' => "Motos", 'varid' => "2"),
array ('name' => "Trucks", 'varid' => "3"),
); 

$mysqlvalue = "2,3"
$mysqlvalue= explode(",",$mysqlvalue);

echo '<select name="vehicles[]" multiple size="6">'."\n";

foreach ($var_options as $arraydes) {
$idvariable = $arraydes[varid];
$namevariable = $arraydes[name];    

    $isSelected = in_array($idvariable,$mysqlvalue) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    if($isSelected != ""){
        echo "<option {$isSelected} value='{$idvariable}'>{$namevariable} (SELECTED)</option>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='{$idvariable}'>{$namevariable}</option>\n";
    }

}
echo "</select>\n";
```

and to save to mysql:

```
$vehicles= implode(', ', $_POST['vehicles']);
```